# AddWebEncoders() how to use it with AZ function?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a simple HTTP Trigger az function and I came across [AddWebEncoders()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.encoderservicecollectionextensions.addwebencoders?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).  The note indicates it adds HTMLEncoder to the services.

I have it as:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>();
    services.AddWebEncoders();
})
.Build();

host.Run();
```

How do I utilize this web encoder in my DataService?
Even without the services.AddWebCoders() I could encode my string in the sample below.  Is there some sort of interface which I can DI into my service class?

```
    public class DataService : IDataService
    {
       public DataService() { }

       public async Task<string> GetHtmlData()
       {
           string encodedData = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode("<img src=x onerror=confirm(\"HACKED\")>");
           return await Task.FromResult(encodedData);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an interface to use in DI, but you should be able to use any class for DI and in this case the HTMLEncoder is an abstract class so I just DI it into my service and use it as normal.

Below is the answer:

```
    public class DataService : IDataService
    {

      private readonly HtmlEncoder _htmlEncoder;

      public DataService(HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder) {

        _htmlEncoder = htmlEncoder;
      }

      public async Task<string> GetHtmlData()
      {
        string encodedData = _htmlEncoder.Encode("<img src=x onerror=confirm(\"HACKED\")>");
        return await Task.FromResult(encodedData);
      }
   }
```